# ORA-00923:FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to execute the script below on sql developer I've got this exception :

> ORA-00923:FROM keyword not found where expected

```
INSERT INTO PROFIL_CADRE_PORTFOLIO (NUMERO_ORDRE, INTITULE_RESSOURCE, ID_NOM_TYPE_DOCUMENT, LIEN_VERS_OBJET, UTILISATEUR_CREATION, DESCRIPTION, DATE_CREATION, UTILISATEUR_MODIFICATION,DATE_MODIFICATION, ID_PROFIL_CADRE)
(SELECT TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ORDRE,
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.RUBRIQUE_DOCUMENT,
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_NOM_TYPE_DOCUMENT,
        CASE
        WHEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.TYPE_PORTFOLIO=1
        THEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.FICHIER_DOCUMENT
        ELSE TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ADRESSE_URL_SITE
        END
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.CREATEUR_PORTFOLIO,
        CASE
        WHEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.TYPE_PORTFOLIO=1
        THEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.TITRE_DOCUMENT
        ELSE TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.TITRE_SITE
        END
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.DATE_CREATION_PORTFOLIO,
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.MODIFICATEUR_PORTFOLIO,
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.DATE_MODIFICATION_PORTFOLIO,
        TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE
FROM TEMPO_PORTFOLIO   
WHERE TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE IN (SELECT distinct(TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE) FROM TEMPO_PORTFOLIO,CV 
                                          WHERE CV.ID_COMPTE_CADRE = TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE
                                          AND CV.CV_WORD IS NOT NULL));
```

I don't get what's wrong with my script.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: No ( ) around the select.

Comment: Looks like you're missing comma's after the `END`s

Comment: Missing comma after `END,` in Case Expression

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. Writing `distinct(TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE)` is useless and exactly the same thing as `distinct TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ID_COMPTE_CADRE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma at the end of this:

```
    CASE
    WHEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.TYPE_PORTFOLIO=1
    THEN TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.FICHIER_DOCUMENT
    ELSE TEMPO_PORTFOLIO.ADRESSE_URL_SITE
    END
```

Same problem with the other `CASE` statement in your query.